# Error converting from xmlschemaset to xmlnode

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read json file and parse using xsd and generate xml output from it. But my code is throwing build error. **cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet' to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test\json1.json"); 
        string xsd = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test\xsd1.xsd"); 
        
        bool isValid = ValidateJsonAgainstXsd(json, xsd);
        if (!isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("JSON is not valid according to the XSD.");
            return;
        }

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
        xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Test\my.xml"); 
    }

    static bool ValidateJsonAgainstXsd(string json, string xsd)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
        
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json).OuterXml);
        
        bool isValid = true;
        xmlDoc.Validate((sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            isValid = false;
        }, schemas);
        
        return isValid;
    }
```

The error comes when its trying to use `schemas` variable

Comment: You say "I am trying to read json file and parse using xsd and generate xml output from it." But actually, my reading of your code is that you a reading a JSON file, converting it to XML using some library, and then checking that the XML that the library produces is valid against your schema. The difference between what your code is doing and what you say it is doing suggests a measure of confusion.

Comment: Do you have a typo?  : JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");  should json be xsd?

Answer (score 0):

From this example: [Validating an XML Document in the DOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/validating-an-xml-document-in-the-dom#validating-an-xml-document-in-the-dom-1), you should add the schema to the `Schemas` property of `XmlDocument` instance.

```cs
static bool ValidateJsonAgainstXsd(string json, string xsd)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json).OuterXml);

    xmlDoc.Schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));

    bool isValid = true;
    xmlDoc.Validate((sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        isValid = false;
                    });

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IK9jCy)

Comment: i dont see where you are using json format. you use xml. You read json file and then apply xsd to it and then produce xml out of it

Comment: Sorry you mean the demo link I shared or? If you are referring to the demo link, yes, my input test data is using XML, then convert it to the JSON as test data to adapt based on the code you provided, which validates the JSON that will be converted into XML for the XML schema.

Comment: Or you can use/fork my demo link, paste your JSON and XML schema to validate the code.

Comment: my json is bit too big so not sure how i attach it to fiddle

Comment: Then, you may write a program and test in your local side. The change is only the `ValidateJsonAgainstXsd` implementation.

Comment: i get error when i use my json saying "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.'" on the line  xmlDoc.LoadXml(JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json)?.OuterXml);

Comment: I think would be great if you can share your JSON along with the xsd file to reproduce the issue. Otherwise you need to add try-catch in the `ValidateJsonAgainstXsd` and return `false` as it unable to deserialize to XML.